# Cambiar de entero a String en data table en primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

En la base de datos los periodos que es lo mismo que el mes esta guardado en números pero quiero convertirlos a String para que el usuario final en la tabla pueda ver los nombres de los meses, el mismo caso pasa con la columna realizada que solo tiene 2 opciones 1 o 0 pero quiero cambiar con pendiente o realizado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigando me encontré con la anotación FacesConverter y cree una clase de la siguiente manera.

```
@FacesConverter(value = "periodoConverter")
public class PeriodoConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String string) {
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object value) {
        int periodo = 1;
        String periodo1 = "";
        if (value != null) {
            switch (periodo) {
                case 1:
                    periodo1 = "Enero";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    periodo1 = "Febrero";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    periodo1 = "Marzo";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    periodo1 = "Abril";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    periodo1 = "Mayo";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    periodo1 = "Junio";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    periodo1 = "Julio";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    periodo1 = "Agosto";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    periodo1 = "Septiembre";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    periodo1 = "Octubre";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    periodo1 = "Noviembre";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    periodo1 = "Diciembre";
                    break;
            }
        }
        return periodo1;
    }

}
```

y en el front:

```
<p:column headerText="Periodo" >
   <h:outputLabel value="#{reg.periodoDatos}" >
      <f:converter converterId="periodoConverter" />
   </h:outputLabel>
</p:column>
```

pero no se por que no funciona y le aparece en blanco, cualquier ayuda se los agradecería de corazón mil gracias.

Comment: No se por que no me apareció el código del front pero es este 

<p:column headerText="Periodo" >
   <h:outputLabel value="#{reg.periodoDatos}" >
      <f:converter converterId="periodoConverter" />
   </h:outputLabel>
</p:column>

Comment: Hola buenas Ricardo. Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir el código del front. Así será mas legible. Un saludo

Comment: Ya lo he editado, una vez que lo revisen aparecerá el código correctamente. Mientras tanto te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: ¿Qué sucede cuando depuras el código del Converter? ¿Llega a pasar por la clase que has creado?

Comment: Si claro pasa por la clase.

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que podrías utilizar esta forma, quizá no es la más óptima pero te podría servir:

```
<p:column headerText="Periodo" >
    <h:outputText value="#{reg.periodoDatos eq 1 ? 'ENERO' : ''}" rendered="#{reg.periodoDatos eq 1}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{reg.periodoDatos eq 2 ? 'FEBRERO' : ''}" rendered="#{reg.periodoDatos eq 2}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{reg.periodoDatos eq 3 ? 'MARZO' : ''}" rendered="#{reg.periodoDatos eq 3}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{reg.periodoDatos eq 4 ? 'ABRIL' : ''}" rendered="#{reg.periodoDatos eq 4}" />
  ............
</p:column>
```

De la misma manera harías con la otra columna:

```
<h:outputText value="#{reg.estado eq 0 ? 'PENDIENTE' : ''}" rendered="#{reg.periodoDatos eq 0}" />
<h:outputText value="#{reg.periodoDatos eq 1 ? 'REALIZADO' : ''}" rendered="#{reg.periodoDatos eq 1}" />
```

El uso del `converter` es para cuando envias los datos en un formulario, si es necesario realizar una conversión entre lo que se muestra en pantalla y lo que se guarda en la base de datos (según mi experiencia).